# Converse of Theorem Proof/Counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

**Theorem**: If $G$ is an abelian group such that $H\leq G$, then $H$ is an abelian subgroup.

I've proved this theorem here:

Proof: Suppose $G$ is abelian. Let $a,b\in G$. Then $ab=ba$ as G is abelian and commutative properties are inherited. Since $H\leq G$, then for all $a,b\in H, ab=ba$ also. Thus, $H$ is abelian.

I am new and still learning how to construct proofs -- please be kind!

The question: Is the converse of the theorem true?

I am having a hard time understanding exactly what the text means by just the converse of the theorem. Are they asking "If $G$ is not an abelian group such that $H\leq G$, then $H$ is not an abelian subgroup? Or, are they asking, "If $G$ is an abelian group such that $H\leq G$, then $H$ is not an abelian subgroup?

If $G$ is an abelian group and if $H\leq G$, then can $H$ be an abelian subgroup? Well, isn't this kind of trivial. Suppose $G$ is abelian. Then laws of commutative properties and other group properties follow; that is, there exist an inverse, identity, and $H$ would also be closed under the binary operations *, where the operation * is associative. Then, wouldn't all elements of $H$ also be abelian since they inherit all these properties from $G$?

Comment: Have you copied the statement of the Theorem exactly word-for-word?  If so, it is poorly worded and it is very unclear what is intended to be the "converse".

Comment: Hi @EricWofsey. Yes, I have. It is poorly worded and I have just reached out to my professor about it.

Answer (score 1):

The converse of a theorem is the statement you obtain when you interchange the hypothesis and the thesis. In this case, the converse should be: "If $G$ is a group such that $H \leq G$ is an abelian subgroup, then $G$ is abelian". You should easily be able to find a counterexample for this claim.

Comment: Referring to the "converse" here is hopelessly ambiguous because it is unclear what is supposed to happen to the quantifiers and the background assumptions.  It's anyone's guess what the author of the problem actually intended.

Comment: For instance, another reasonable "converse" would be: if $G$ is a group such that every subgroup of $G$ is abelian, then $G$ is abelian.  Or another one: if $G$ is an abelian group and $H$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$, then $H\leq G$.  Your interpretation is probably the most likely one since it is the most interesting one I can think of but really it is a terribly written problem.

Comment: You're right, reading it better the text is indeed ambiguous. I thought the statement I wrote was the most natural possible converse, even if thinking better I know it is wrong. In particular it's likely that the author intended the first one you give, even if there's no reason to prefer either of them. Thank you for your pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The converse, $G$ has an abelian subgroup implies $G$ is abelian, is false.  Consider $V_4\le S_4$ (either the normal one, or one of the nonnormal ones).  Or, any cyclic subgroup of any $S_n$.  Or any cyclic subgroup of your favorite nonabelian group.

The other possible interpretations appear to be trivial.